# Azure SQL database - GraphQL

Tags: azure, graphql

Does anybody know if there is a way you can import data into an Azure SQL Database, using an GraphQL API? Or if you could create a connection within an iPaas system to send data to the Azure SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to exchange data between **azure sql database** and **GraphQl**.
**Directus** can be used which is an open-source Data Platform that enables anyone to access and manage the database content.
**Directus** will give us a GraphQl API to be used with the data .

Refer the following [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/automatic-graphql-and-rest-endpoint-for-azure-sql-with-directus/?msclkid=14aca514b36211ec8c9921226f0ff5f2) to setup the azure sql database and directus .